# Brunch: how to wrap vendor code in AMD modules?

Tags: javascript, brunch

I want all vendor code to be wrapped in AMD modules.
I have defined this section in my config.coffee:

```
modules:
    wrapper: 'amd'
    definition: 'amd'
```

But it seems like brunch uses AMD optimizer only for 'app' folder files. All vendor js files where concatinated without any r.js-like preprocessing(no module names added in "define(...)" statements). As a result, Almond(it's almost the same as RequireJS) complains about anonymous module definition during vendor file executing.

Here is my full config:

```
exports.config =

  paths:
    public: 'public'

  files:
    javascripts:
      defaultExtension: 'js'

      joinTo:
        'js/app.js': /^app/
        'js/vendor.js': /^vendor[\\/](?!mocha|chai|sinon|sinon-chai)/
        'js/tests.js': /^test/
        'js/tests-vendor.js': /^vendor[\\/](?=mocha|chai|sinon|sinon-chai)/

      order:
        before: [
          'bower_components/almond/almond.js',
          'bower_components/jquery/jquery.js',
          'bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.underscore.js'
        ]

    stylesheets:
      defaltExtension: 'less'

      joinTo:
        'css/styles.css': /^(vendor[\\/](?!mocha|chai|sinon|sinon-chai)|app)/
        'css/tests-vendor.css': /^(vendor[\\/](?=mocha|chai|sinon|sinon-chai))/

    templates:
      defaultExtension: 'hbs'
      joinTo: 'js/app.js'

  modules:
    wrapper: 'amd'
    definition: 'amd'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `conventions.vendor` in your config to something that won't match your vendor files in order to enable module wrapping.

https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/master/docs/config.md#conventions

Comment: Thank you, it works for vendor files now. But I faced another issue. I would like to use handlebars templates in my project. So I added this lines in my config: 
 <plugins:
  handlebars:
    include:
   runtime: false
   amd: true>

But there is some code (i.e. handlebars-brunch/ns.js) that expect Handlebars in global scope. So, is there a way to export Handlebars in global scope along with possibility to use it as AMD module?

Comment: I'm going to create separate question for this.

Comment: Your new question was more general, so that's how it got answered. But in the particular case you're describing, the issue may be that the [ns.js](https://github.com/brunch/handlebars-brunch/blob/master/ns.js) script baked into the handlebars-brunch plugin was not made to be compatible with the `amd` option, and a PR needs to be filed with that project to get it resolved. Perhaps a `ns.amd.js` will be necessary.

Comment: Although I'm not sure if it's only an issue when you mess with `conventions.vendor`, in which case *not* overriding it, but instead putting the vendor scripts you want wrapped in a differently named directory as described in that other answer may be your solution.