# Brunch: How to correctly deal with AMD and vendor code?

Tags: javascript, brunch

I really like AMD-like syntax for modules management in js. Now i'm trying to figure out how can I use require.js with brunch.
This is what I want to achieve:

1. All vendor code should be concatenated in one file.
2. Exported vendor symbols should be available in global scope(since
   some 3rd-party code EXCPECT to find it there).
3. I want to use require.js or Almod for module management.

The problem is if I load require.js some of vendor scripts are trying to define anonymous module. Here is a code snipped from Backbone for reference:

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['underscore', 'jquery', 'exports'], function(_, $, exports) {
      //...
    });
```

}

As a result, require.js complains about anonymous module definition.

Answer (score 0):

This is why wrapping of vendor code is disabled by default in Brunch. Many vendor scripts have UMD or their own way of exposing their API that is incompatible with generic module wrapping, but they will work out of the box with your AMD structure if left alone.

What you may want to do is organize your vendor scripts into separate directories by the ones that need wrapping by Brunch and the ones that don't; something like the `vendor` and `vendor-wrapped`. Using default `conventions` settings, Brunch will wrap the scripts in `vendor-wrapped` and not the ones in `vendor`. Then you can concatenate them both together (based on [your prior question's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29920466/brunch-how-to-wrap-vendor-code-in-amd-modules)):

```
      joinTo:
          'js/vendor.js': /^vendor(-wrapped)?[\\/](?!mocha|chai|sinon|sinon-chai)/
```

There is still the possibility that you'll encounter some vendor scripts that are structured in such a way as to just be incompatible with AMD, even when wrapped, and in those cases your choices are to either not use those libs, work with the authors to get them updated, or maintain your own modifications to make them compatible with your project.

Comment: It's not a very convenient to organize vendor code "By hands". For example, it turned out that it's impossible to use requre.js along with Bower packages?

Comment: It's up to your choice of dependencies you want to use. If using AMD is an absolute requirement for you, you may have to limit your dependency choices to those that are already AMD compatible.